# Avoid RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.lock RuntimeException (timeout)?

Tags: java, processing, jogl

I have an application that loads a series of large images on startup.  This is a [Processing](http://processing.org/) application, so most things run on the single main animation thread, and it's using Processing's OpenGL renderer.

**EDIT:** the RuntimeException is thrown when some process within JOGL takes > 5 seconds.  Making it back up the stack to subsequent `loadImage()` calls means the RuntimeException is avoided.  I'm not clear yet how to repro this and so haven't found a way around it save the ugly try-catch + reflection workaround [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/jogamp-common-util-locks-RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish-lock-timeout-exception-td3999944.html).

<s>The image loads sometimes take longer than 5 seconds, and when they do, JOGL throws a RuntimeException from within `RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.lock()`.</s> My understanding is that `RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.lock()` complains if the main GL animation thread halts execution for > 5 seconds.

<s>Is there a simple fix for this?  I *could* shift the image loads to a different thread and reshuffle my init sequence to be more asynchronous, but that's a lot of work for something that happens only once, on application init, at a time when the application has plenty of time to start up regardless.</s>

(Note: this is for an installation, no one will be present or trying to use the application when it first launches in the morning, so a delay of many seconds on init is not a problem.)

Comment: you couldn't, because Processing is not multithreaded. You could use plain Java and write a multithreaded application that just makes use of Processing as a library for doing drawing, but if you're waiting for resources, first try the "async" methods provided by Processing such as requestImage (rather than loadImage), and if those don't work, it's probably plain java time.

Comment: There is a topic about this in Processing wiki, not sure though if this is your case... http://wiki.processing.org/w/Asynchronous_data/image_loading  Also there is one about threading: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Threading

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans forgot about `requestImage()`.  that'll probably do the trick.